# What is the true maximum (and minimum) value of Random.nextGaussian()?

Tags: java, random

In theory, the bounds for `nextGaussian` are meant to be positive and negative infinity. But since `Random.nextDouble`, which is used to calculate the Gaussian random number, doesn't come infinitely close to 0 and 1, there is a practical limit to `nextGaussian`. And `Random.next` is also not a perfectly uniform distribution.

It was theorised that the maximum should be about 2.2042*10^17 and related to the 53 bit shift of `nextDouble` ([reference](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/508317357228294146/545718295408541716/unknown.png)), but that is likely just an upper bound.

The answer probably depends on the distribution of `Random.next` and the exact implementation of `StrictMath.sqrt` and `StrictMath.log`. I couldn't find much information about either.

And yes, I know that the outer values are extremely unlikely, but it can be relevant, for example in the context of RNG manipulation in games.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you looked at the Java source code for these methods? That will probably give you the answer.

Comment: For the `Random` class, yes, for the `StrictMath` class there's no source code where I looked (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html). Also, it doesn't just give the answer, it needs quite a bit of analysis, not all parts I understand.

Comment: This is investigated by [Daniel Jelinski](https://plus.google.com/100071354825362615095) in his blog ([part 1](http://djssoft.blogspot.com/2017/07/range-of-randomnextgaussian.html), [part 2](https://djssoft.blogspot.com/2017/07/range-of-randomnextgaussian-continued.html)). He said: "*The lowest value found was: -7.844680087923773 (on second call to nextGaussian with seed = 994892). The highest value found was: 7.995084298635286 (on first call to nextGaussian with seed = 14005843). These are the real maximum & minimum values returned by Oracle Java 8 implementation of nextGaussian.*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Random Implementation

The most important thing you will have to know for this answer is the implementation of `Random.nextGaussian`:

```java
synchronized public double nextGaussian() {
    // See Knuth, ACP, Section 3.4.1 Algorithm C.
    if (haveNextNextGaussian) {
        haveNextNextGaussian = false;
        return nextNextGaussian;
    } else {
        double v1, v2, s;
        do {
            v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
            v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
        nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
        haveNextNextGaussian = true;
        return v1 * multiplier;
    }
}
```

And the implementation of `Random.nextDouble`:

```
public double nextDouble() {
    return (double) (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) / (1L << 53);
}
```

First, I want to draw your attention to the fact that `nextGaussian` generates 2 values at a time, and that depending on whether you know how many `nextGaussian` calls have passed since the last time the seed was set, you may be able to use a slightly lower max value for odd vs even numbers of calls.
From now on, I'm going to call the two maximums v1_max and v2_max, referring to whether the value was generated by `v1 * multiplier` or `v2 * multiplier`.

## The Answer

With that out of the way let's cut straight to the chase and explain later:

```
|      |Value             |Seed*          |
|------|------------------|---------------|
|v1_max|7.995084298635286 |97128757896197 |
|v2_max|7.973782613935931 |10818416657590 |
|v1_min|-7.799011049744149|119153396299238|
|v2_min|-7.844680087923773|10300138714312 |
* Seeds for v2 need to have nextGaussian called twice before you see the value listed.
```

## A Closer Look at nextGaussian

The answers by @KaptainWutax and @Marco13 have already gone into detail about the same things, but I think seeing things on a graph makes things clearer. Let's focus on v1_max, the other three values hold very similar logic. I'm going to plot `v1` on the x-axis, `v2` on the y-axis and `v1 * multiplier` on the z-axis.

[image: Graph]

Our eyes immediately jump to the maximum point at `v1` = 0, `v2` = 0, `v1 * multiplier` = infinity. But if you notice in the do-while loop, it explicitly disallows this situation. Therefore, it's clear from the graph that the actual v1_max must have a slightly higher `v1` value, but not much higher. Also noteworthy is that for any `v1` value > 0, the maximum `v1 * multiplier` is at `v2` = 0.

Our method to find v1_max will be to count up `v1` from zero (or, more specifically, counting the `nextDouble` which generated it up from 0.5, incrementing in steps of 2^-53, as per the implementation of `nextDouble`). But, just knowing `v1`, how do we get the other variables, and the `v1 * multiplier` for that `v1`?

## Reversing nextDouble

It turns out that knowing the output of a `nextDouble` call is enough to determine the seed of the `Random` object that generated it at the time. Intuitively, this is because looking at the `nextDouble` implementation, it "looks like" there should be 2^54 possible outputs - but the seed of `Random` is only 48-bit. Furthermore, it's possible to recover this seed in much faster time than brute force.

I initially tried a naive approach based on using `next(27)` directly to get bits of the seed then brute-forcing the remaining 21 bits, but this proved too slow to be useful. Then SicksonFSJoe gave me a much faster method to extract a seed from a single `nextDouble` call. Note that to understand the details of this method you will have to know the implementation of `Random.next`, and a little modular arithmetic.

```java
private static long getSeed(double val) {
    long lval = (long) (val * (1L << 53));
    // let t = first seed (generating the high bits of this double)
    // let u = second seed (generating the low bits of this double)
    long a = lval >> 27; // a is the high 26 bits of t
    long b = lval & ((1 << 27) - 1); // b is the high 27 bits of u

    // ((a << 22) + c) * 0x5deece66d + 0xb = (b << 21) + d (mod 2**48)
    // after rearranging this gives
    // (b << 21) - 11 - (a << 22) * 0x5deece66d = c * 0x5deece66d - d (mod 2**48)
    // and because modular arithmetic
    // (b << 21) - 11 - (a << 22) * 0x5deece66d + (k << 48) = c * 0x5deece66d - d
    long lhs = ((b << 21) - 0xb - (a << 22) * 0x5deece66dL) & 0xffffffffffffL;

    // c * 0x5deece66d is 56 bits max, which gives a max k of 375
    // also check k = 65535 because the rhs can be negative
    for (long k = 65535; k != 376; k = k == 65535 ? 0 : k + 1) {
        // calculate the value of d
        long rem = (0x5deece66dL - (lhs + (k << 48))) % 0x5deece66dL;
        long d = (rem + 0x5deece66dL) % 0x5deece66dL; // force positive
        if (d < (1 << 21)) {
            // rearrange the formula to get c
            long c = lhs + d;
            c *= 0xdfe05bcb1365L; // = 0x5deece66d**-1 (mod 2**48)
            c &= 0xffffffffffffL;
            if (c < (1 << 22)) {
                long seed = (a << 22) + c;
                seed = ((seed - 0xb) * 0xdfe05bcb1365L) & 0xffffffffffffL; // run the LCG forwards one step
                return seed;
            }
        }
    }

    return Long.MAX_VALUE; // no seed
}
```

Now we can get the seed from a `nextDouble`, it makes sense that we can iterate over `v1` values rather than seeds.

## Bringing it All Together

An outline of the algorithm is as follows:

1. Initialize `nd1` (stands for `nextDouble` 1) to 0.5
2. While the upper bound and our current v1_max haven't crossed, repeat steps 3-7
3. Increment `nd1` by 2^-53
4. Compute `seed` from `nd1` (if it exists), and generate `nd2`, `v1`, `v2` and `s`
5. Check the validity of `s`
6. Generate a gaussian, compare with v1_max
7. Set a new upper bound by assuming `v2` = 0

And here is a Java implementation. You can verify the values I gave above for yourself if you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double upperBound;
    double nd1 = 0.5, nd2;
    double maxGaussian = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    long maxSeed = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    long seed;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        nd1 += 0x1.0p-53;
        seed = getSeed(nd1);

        double v1, v2, s;
        v1 = 2 * nd1 - 1;

        if (seed != Long.MAX_VALUE) { // not no seed
            rand.setSeed(seed ^ 0x5deece66dL);
            rand.nextDouble(); // nd1
            nd2 = rand.nextDouble();

            v2 = 2 * nd2 - 1;
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
            if (s < 1 && s != 0) { // if not, another seed will catch it
                double gaussian = v1 * StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s) / s);
                if (gaussian > maxGaussian) {
                    maxGaussian = gaussian;
                    maxSeed = seed;
                }
            }
        }

        upperBound = v1 * StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(v1 * v1) / (v1 * v1));
        if (i++ % 100000 == 0)
            System.out.println(maxGaussian + " " + upperBound);
    } while (upperBound > maxGaussian);
    System.out.println(maxGaussian + " " + maxSeed);
}
```

One final catch to watch out for, this algorithm will get you the internal seeds for the `Random`. To use it in `setSeed`, you have to xor them with the `Random`'s multiplier, `0x5deece66dL` (which has already been done for you in the table above).

Comment: I wonder why `nextGaussian` generates two numbers at a time. I can imagine that this can cause quite the headache when setting a seed and expecting it to be applied on the next call.

Comment: @FabianRöling you will always get the same value from `nextGaussian` after setting the same seed, since the `haveNextNextGaussian` flag is set to false when setting the seed.

Comment: Also a great answer, I'd still have to allocate more time in order to read (i.e. "understand") it more thoroughly. But one important point: Please don't call it `v1-max`. This looks like a subtraction. Calling it `v1max` or `maxV1` or so would make *much* clearer that this is only a single value.

Answer (score 7):

So everything I will say here is purely theoretical, and I am still working on a GPU program to scan the whole seed base.

The nextGaussian() method is implemented as such.

```
private double nextNextGaussian;
private boolean haveNextNextGaussian = false;

 public double nextGaussian() {

   if (haveNextNextGaussian) {

     haveNextNextGaussian = false;
     return nextNextGaussian;

   } else {

     double v1, v2, s;

     do {
       v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
       v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
       s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
     } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);

     double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
     nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
     haveNextNextGaussian = true;
     return v1 * multiplier;

   }

 }
```

The most interesting part has to be at the end, [return v1 * multiplier]. Because v1 cannot be larger than 1.0D, we need to find a way to increase the size of the multiplier, which is implemented as follows.

```
double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
```

The only variable being "s", it is safe to establish that the lower "s" is, the bigger the multiplier will get. All good? Let's keep going.

```
 do {
   v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
   v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
   s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
 } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
```

This tells us that "s" has to belong to the ]0,1[ number set and that the lowest value we're looking for is just a little bigger than zero. "S" is declared with the sum of squares of "v1" and "v2". To get the smallest theoretical value, v2 needs to be zero and v1 needs to be as small as it can possibly get. Why "theoretical"? Because they are generated from nextDouble() calls. There is no guarantee that the seed base contains those 2 consecutive numbers.

Let's have fun now!

Lowest value "v1" can hold is the double's epsilon, which is 2^(-1022). Making our way back, to get such a number, nextDouble would need to generate (2^(-1022) + 1) / 2.

That is...very very very disturbing. I'm not an expert, but I am pretty sure many bits are gonna get lost, and floating-point errors are to be expected.

It is probably(most definitely) impossible for a nextDouble to generate such a value, but the goal is to find a value as close as possible to that number.

Just for the fun of it, let's do the full math to find the answer. StrictMath.log() is implemented as the natural log. I haven't looked into it's precision, but let's assume there was no limitations on that level. The highest nextGaussian would be calculated as...

```
= (-2 * ln(v1 * v1) / (v1 * v1)) * v1 
= (-2 * ln(EPSILON^2) / (EPSILON^2)) * EPSILON

where EPSILON is equal to 2^(-1022).
```

Believe it or not, I could barely find any calculator that accepted such small numbers, but I finally opted for [this high precision calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/calculator).

By plugging in this equation,

> (-2 * ln((2^(-1022))^2) / ((2^(-1022))^2)) * (2^(-1022))

I got,

> 1.273479378356503041913108844696651886724617446559145569961266215283953862086306158E+311

Pretty big huh? Well...it's definitely not going to be that big...but it's nice to take into account. Hope my reasoning makes sense and don't be shy to point out any mistake I made.

As I said at the start, I am working on a program to bruteforce all seeds and find the actual lowest value. I'll keep you updated.

**EDIT :**

Sorry for the late response. After bruteforcing 2^48 seeds in about 10 hours, I found the EXACT same answers as Earthcomputer.

Comment: What an amazing first post for this account. :D And on the first try even (no edits)! I won't mark it as accepted for now, since that's just an upper bound. Considering wither skulls, I guess an upper bound of 10^311 doesn't really help much in proving a design to be 100% reliable. If that's a motion value or something like that, it would fly to the farlands in less than a frame. To everyone else reading this, being probably very confused: We're both in the same chat where this question originated from. It all makes sense in context.

Comment: Haha, thank you! :D <3 I think it's much better to talk about it here. I couldn't find any post of anyone attempting to find the actual upper bound even though I'm pretty sure a bunch of people want to know. Also, there are way smarter people around who could probably help.

Comment: Indeed, a great answer. But it will take some more investigation to find the final truth here. You said *"To get the smallest theoretical value, v2 needs to be zero and v1 needs to be as small as it can possibly get."*. The point is: When `v1` is small, then the final result will also be small. The *actual* maximum will pobably have to be fought out between the `log(s)/s` part and the `v1 * ...` part, and this is where it gets complicated...

Comment: You should not worry about that. While v1 gets linearly smaller, log(s)/s gets exponentially bigger. v1's value is not a big deal.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that (mentioned in my answer as well). However, the mutual influences here are not trivial, and my answer has to be considered to be no more than a "reasonable guess". Let's see whether someone finds a line of argumentation where a value larger than ~12 can be achieved.

Answer (score 4):

My bet is on **12.00727336061225**.

The reasoning behind that is roughly along the lines of the [answer by KaptainWutax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54717660/3182664) : Considering the `log(s)/s` part for the multiplier, the goal must be to make `s` as small as possible. This comes with the additional constraint that `v1` will be part of the result. So essentially

- `v1` has to be small, so that `s` is small
- `v1` has to be large, so that the final result is large

But since the division by `s` will grow exponentially as `s` approaches zero, this will overweigh contribution of the factor `v1`.

So to summarize that line of thought:

The essential part of the implementation of `Random#nextGaussian` is that one:

```
double nextGaussian() {
    double v1, v2, s;
    do {
        v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
        v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1 and 1
        s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
    } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
    double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
    return v1 * multiplier;
}
```

The `Random#nextDouble` method is implemented like this:

```
double nextDouble() {
    return (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 53);
}
```

where `next(n)` returns an integer where the lowest `n` bits are set randomly.

In order to maximize the value of `nextGaussian`, one can argue:

- The value of `s` must be as close as possible to `0.0` (but just not `0.0`)
- Therefore, the "best" value for `v2` will be `0.0`, and the "best" value for `v1` will be the smallest value that can be the result of `2 * nextDouble() - 1`
- In order to have `v2==0.0`, we assume that the random bits in the `nextDouble` call are `0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L` - in this case, `nextDouble` will return `0.5`, and `v2` will be `0.0`
- The bits that would cause the smallest valid value for `v1` would then be `0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001L` - just one annoying bit at the end, causing `nextDouble` to return `0.5000000000000001`, yielding a value of `2.220446049250313E-16` for `v1`
- Given these values, `s` will be `4.930380657631324E-32`, the multiplier will be `5.4075951832589016E16`, and the final result will be

  ## 12.00727336061225

Here is an example where you can play around with the bit combinations that *might* be returned by the `Random#next` calls that are the basis for the whole computation here. Maybe someone finds a combination that yields a higher value...?

```
public class LargestNextGaussian
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Random#nextDouble is implemented as 
        //   (((long)next(26) << 27) + next(27)) / (double)(1L << 53)
        // The "baseValue" here refers to the value that
        // is obtained by combining the results of the 
        // two calls to "next"

        long baseValueForV1 = 
            0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001L;
        double valueForV1 = 
            baseValueForV1 / (double)(1L << 53);

        long baseValueForV2 = 
            0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L;
        double valueForV2 = 
            baseValueForV2 / (double)(1L << 53);

        // As of Random#nextGaussian:
        double v1, v2, s;
        do {
            v1 = 2 * valueForV1 - 1;
            v2 = 2 * valueForV2 - 1;
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
        double result = v1 * multiplier;

        System.out.println("baseValueForV1 " + Long.toBinaryString(baseValueForV1));
        System.out.println("baseValueForV2 " + Long.toBinaryString(baseValueForV2));
        System.out.println("valueForV1     " + valueForV1);
        System.out.println("valueForV2     " + valueForV2);
        System.out.println("v1             " + v1);
        System.out.println("v2             " + v2);
        System.out.println("s              " + s);
        System.out.println("multiplier     " + multiplier);
        System.out.println("result         " + result);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output is, as summarized above:

```
baseValueForV1 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
baseValueForV2 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
valueForV1     0.5000000000000001
valueForV2     0.5
v1             2.220446049250313E-16
v2             0.0
s              4.930380657631324E-32
multiplier     5.4075951832589016E16
result         12.00727336061225
```

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation, I really underestimated how quick it grows. It makes perfect sense for it to be 12.

Answer (score -2):

here ya go:

`long seed=97128757896197L;
Random r= new Random(seed );
System.out.println(r.nextGaussian());
System.out.println(r.nextGaussian());`

7.995084298635286
0.8744239748619776

Comment: Nice to know that that number is possible, I guess, but that doesn't say if it's the maximum.

Comment: lets wait for earth essay then we will see ^_^